# Why is sql server query returning results and linq query is not

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a linq query that is not returning results

```
PermitsList = (from n in context.Permits
              join d in context.TrafficDisruptions on n.GUID equals d.PermitGUID
              select n);
```

I know that this sql query does return the expected results

```
SELECT * FROM [KEPT].[dbo].[Permit] p join TrafficDisruption d on p.GUID = d.PermitGUID
```

Any idea on why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Is `PermitsList` lazy loading? Maybe try calling `.ToList()` against the LINQ query, or log the SQL that EF is executing via `context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);` (somewhere before the query is executed...)

Comment: Attach a profiling tool and capture the SQL generated from your linq?

Comment: Are you positive you're connecting to the same database in both cases?

Comment: In your sql, the Permit table is qualified in "KEPT" db, is that correct, and is context.Permits also specified in that db?

Comment: These tables are both in the same database, yes.

Comment: LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. Instead of joining two *entity sets*, make sure `Permit` has a `Disruptions` collection. No need to join, the disruptions will be loaded lazily when needed

Comment: One thing I probably should have included with this question is that my permits list is of type IQueryable. `IQueryable<Permit> PermitsList;`

Comment: What is the generated SQL (`PermitsList.ToString()`)?

Comment: The internal query was too many characters to include all, but here. `SELECT 
    [Extent1].[GUID] AS [GUID], 
    [Extent1].[TrafficDisruptions] AS [TrafficDisruptions]
    FROM  [dbo].[Permit] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TrafficDisruption] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[GUID] = [Extent2].[PermitGUID]}` Also wanted to note that TrafficDisruptions is also a bool field in Permit Table.

Comment: Does your app's connection string [use `AttachDbFileName`](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/)? If so, it is using a different (empty) copy of the database than your query in SSMS. Stop using that "feature"...

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Does the `Permit` table live in a different database than the `TrafficDisruptions` table? It looks like you own SQL is explicitly referencing a `KEPT` db. If yes, you might need a second `DbContext` or a linked table if you'd like to stick with just the one.

Answer (score 4):

If you're GUIDs are being represented as strings in your models you might be running into a bug in LINQ to Entities with case sensitivity.

If joining on a string field and the cases of the strings are different SQL will return the correct results (assuming the collation of your database isn't case sensitive) but LINQ will fail to match the foreign keys correctly. This happens both in queries and in navigation properties.

This might not be your issue but might be something to look at.

Comment: This is a good thought, however I don't think this is my issue as both data types in sql server are uniqueidentifier.

Comment: *but LINQ will fail to match the foreign keys correctly* Why? The LINQ query should be translated to SQL, no?

Comment: It retrieves all the data correctly but when it goes to turn them into models it matches again in c# which is always case sensitive. At that point it fails.

Comment: @Chris yeah then they should both be returning with the same casing. Just thought it might be worth a shot.